# Неверный вывод результата из цикла

Tags: plsql, cursor

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему результатом запроса является вывод чисел с 1 по 5 три раза вместо последовательности с 1 до 15?

```
declare

cursor allrow_cur is     
select rownum as row_num
from dual 
connect by level <= 15;
type cur IS TABLE OF allrow_cur%ROWTYPE; 

basket_type_l cur;

begin
    OPEN allrow_cur;
    loop
      FETCH allrow_cur BULK COLLECT INTO basket_type_l LIMIT 5;
      --exit when allrow_cur%notfound;
      exit when basket_type_l.count=0;
      for i in 1 .. basket_type_l.count 
        loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
      end loop ;
    END LOOP;
    close allrow_cur;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Понял в чем проблема, надо было написать

```
dbms_output.put_line(basket_type_l(i).row_num)
```

Но возник другой вопрос, как передать все столбцы сразу? Без перебора
Что-то в этом плане

```
dbms_output.put_line(basket_type_l(i).*)
```

Comment: Если появился новый вопрос, то задайте его как новый вопрос, а не ответ. На ответ вам никто не ответит.